# Insertar datos en base de datos desde formulario

Tags: php, html, mysqli

basicamente esta es la cuestion, tengo un formulario que realice en php, lo tengo dividido en dos secciones, uno es la validacion de los datos y en el otro el formulario, quiero insertar los datos de ese formulario en una base de datos que previamente ya cree, lo que no se es como realizar la estructura de INSERT INTO con mysqli, les dejo el codigo, o sea basicamente no se donde deberia incluir el INSERT ya que nunca habia trabajado antes con php, aclarando que soy nuevo en todo eso, gracias.

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario Contacto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos-user.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uname" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (!$enviado && isset($Uname)) echo $Uname ?>">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="wwid" placeholder="WWID" value="<?php if (!$enviado && isset($WWID)) echo $WWID ?>">

            <?php if (!empty($errores)): ?>
                <div class="alert error">
                    <?php echo $errores; ?>
                </div>
            <?php elseif ($enviado): ?>
                <div class="alert success">
                    <p>Enviado correctamente</p>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php 

$enviado = '';
$errores = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $WWID = $_POST['wwid'];

    #Validar nombre
    if (!empty($Uname)) {
        $Uname = trim($Uname); #Evitar que el usuario escriba espacios al inicio y al final
        $Uname = filter_var($Uname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un nombre <br />';
    }
    #Validar WWID
    if (!empty($WWID)) {
        $WWID = trim($WWID); #Evitar que el usuario escriba espacios al inicio y al final
        $WWID = filter_var($WWID, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un WWID <br />';
    }

    if (!$errores) {
        $enviado = true;
    }

}

require 'index_view-user.php';

 ?>
```

Comment: Según la lógica de tu código, la inserción debes ejecutarla dentro de este bloque: `if (!$errores) {
        $enviado = true; }`

Comment: Gracias por responder entonces seria de la siguiente forma?
```
if (!$errores) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user(uname, wwid) VALUES($Uname, $WWID)";
  $enviado = true;
 }
´´´
otra parte que no entiendo es donde deberia de incluir el require para abrir la conexion a la bae de datos y como se deberia cerrar esa conexion

Comment: Correcto. En cuanto a tus otras preguntas, es mejor que leas la documentación de PHP sobre mysqli, está muy bien explicado todo y además en español. Este  sitio es para dudas puntuales. Aquí también hay varias preguntas que versas sobre el uso de mysqli, pero por la naturaleza de Stackoverflow, no se pueden aclarar todas las dudas sobre un asunto en una sola pregunta. Para hacer lo que quieres hay varios métodos, el que más me gusta es tener una clase que gestione la conexión y usar instancias de esa clase cuando necesite algo de la base de datos. Esa clase puede tener su método cerrar.

Comment: Gracias por tus respuestas, voy a consultar la documentacion, excelente dia